# where is the conf directory of Cloudera hadoop located?

Tags: apache, hadoop, cloudera

I've been searching for the location where the Cloudera Hadoop `/conf` directory is located but I couldn't find it. I installed the `namenode` using Cloudera's one-click package repo, and I ran `sudo apt-get install -y hadoop-hdfs-namenode`, but now I need to find the `/conf` so I can configure a Hadoop cluster.
Does someone know where is it located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is in the usual place, `/etc/hadoop/conf`. You will find this is actually a symlink that uses `alternatives`, but you can just go to this directory to find/edit config if needed.

However it's much easier to manage the packages and config via Cloudera Manager. I really wouldn't bother with editing them manually.

Comment: The thing is I'm trying to create persistent cluster and Cloudera Manager only creates the instances temporarily

Comment: What do you mean by persistent?  CM isn't temporary.

Answer (score 0):

Conf files are located under /etc/hadoop/conf

you can use command to see the list of all configuration files:

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ ls -lart /etc/hadoop/conf/
```